# How to send clicked item as parameter in an ListView item binding

Tags: binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a dynamic list and it is the source of a `ListView`. 
I have a command in the `ViewModel`, where I need to receive the item, which was clicked. I want to get the object that represents that item, so I can perform a change on it.

I am using MvvmCross.

Answer (score 1):

That is fairly trivial. I imagine you have a `ListView` in your layout which looks something like:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
   ...
   local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items" />
```

To be able to get the clicked item you just add a command to [`ItemClick`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxListView.cs#L79):

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
   ...
   local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemClick ItemClickedCommand" />
```

Then in your `ViewModel` you should have an `ItemClickedCommand`:

```
private MvxCommand<ItemViewModel> _itemClickedCommand;
public ICommand ItemClickedCommand
{
    get 
    { 
        return _itemClickedCommand = _itemClickedCommand ??
            new MvxCommand<ItemViewModel>(item => {
                // do something with the item here
            }):
    }
}
```

Where `ItemViewModel` is the type of the items in the collection you have bound to the `ItemsSource`.